# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac1{n^3}\sum\limits_{\ell=1}^{n-1}\sqrt{(n^2-\ell^2)(n^2-(\ell-1)^2)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Along the way to proving a solution for [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177411/volume-and-surface-area-of-a-sphere-by-polyhedral-approximation) stubborn question of mine, I've come upon this expression which I would like to evaluate:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{\ell=1}^{n-1}\sqrt{(n^2-\ell^2)(n^2-(\ell-1)^2)} 
$$
Assuming consistency+correctness of the rest of my work, I would love for it to turn out that the limit is $\frac{2}{3}$, but to be honest I'm not certain of how to continue. I see no reason for there to be a nice closed form for the sum (and W|A appear to agree).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every $1\leqslant\ell\leqslant n-1$, 
$$
n^2-\ell^2\leqslant\sqrt{(n^2-\ell^2)(n^2-(\ell-1)^2)}\leqslant n^2-(\ell-1)^2,
$$
hence the sums $S_n$ you are interested in are such that $R_n\leqslant S_n\leqslant T_n$ for every $n\geqslant1$, with
$$
R_n=\frac1{n^3}\sum_{\ell=1}^{n-1}(n^2-\ell^2),\qquad T_n=\frac1{n^3}\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-2}(n^2-\ell^2).
$$
The rest should be easy (and the limit is indeed $\frac23$).

Comment: Excellent! And, thrilled to see that the solution is correct. I'm going to write up an answer to the old question now.

Comment: I wonder the question @did can not solve...

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/181997/34515) is what I ended up doing with this. Thanks again!